# Как сделать превью для видео из изображений?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать превью для видео как на pornhub? При наведении показывается видео в миниатюре.
Сейчас я использую cover изображение которое при нажатии заменяется на iframe в JavaScript.
В iframe находится видео.
Я хочу добавить что-бы при наведении :hover показывалось как-бы урезанная часть того видео.
Я поглядел они используют около 16 изображений этого видео и как-бы запускают их как слайдер.
Может кто-то знает как это реализовано?
Я не хочу придумывать велосипед :) и пытаться привязывать слайдер из превьюшек для видео на :hover.

Если интересно посмотреть кому-то как я повесил cover изображение на видео.
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/brendan8c/pen/KKaWdPL)

**HTML**

```
   <header class="header">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="video_box">
                <div class="cover_img"></div>
                <a class="play-link">
                    <div class="play-icon">
                        <svg fill-opacity=".8" width="50" height="50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                            <path fill="white" d="M371.7 238l-176-107c-15.8-8.8-35.7 2.5-35.7 21v208c0 18.4 19.8 29.8 35.7 21l176-101c16.4-9.1 16.4-32.8 0-42zM504 256C504 119 393 8 256 8S8 119 8 256s111 248 248 248 248-111 248-248zm-448 0c0-110.5 89.5-200 200-200s200 89.5 200 200-89.5 200-200 200S56 366.5 56 256z">
                            </path>
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

**CSS**

```
.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 540px;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    height: 540px;
    background-color: #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px 1px #000;
}

.video_box {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.cover_img {
    background-image: url(http://img.youtube.com/vi/736fiBMtADg/0.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
}

.play-link {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.play-icon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    transition: all ease-in-out .2s;
    svg {
        path {
            stroke: #ff8562;
            stroke-width: 10px;
            fill: #ffffff;
        }
    }
    &:hover {
        transform: scale(1.4);
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
const videoBtn = document.querySelector('.play-link');
const videoBox = document.querySelector('.video_box');

videoBtn.addEventListener('click', playVideo);

function playVideo() {
    const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.className = 'iframe';
    iframe.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/736fiBMtADg?autoplay=1';
    videoBox.replaceWith(iframe); 
};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должен сказать, что я нашёл [этот репозеторий](https://github.com/wangweiwei/video-metadata-thumbnails) 
Удобный метод (или объект Video) для получения метаданных и эскизов видео Blob в формате HTML5.
Но это наверное не то, что мне нужно. По крайней мере оно получает кадры из видео но не более.

Comment: Не [оно](http://techslides.com/make-animated-gifs-from-videos-with-html5)?

Comment: Да возможно оно.. Я так понимаю там создают анимцию из этих изображений а потом можно её повесить на hover эффект.. Нужно попробовать!